# Error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object Generating Each Day of Year

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, datetime, strtotime

I have a Calendar Class Where i Input the year Only from the user and generate the whole days of year and save in database.

```
class Calendar
{
   /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="today_date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $todayDate;
    /**
     * @var boolean $isBusinessDay
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_business_day", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $isBusinessDay;
    /**
     * @var boolean $isHoliday
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_holiday", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $isHoliday;
    /**
     * @var time $openTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="open_time", type="time", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $openTime;
    /**
     * @var time $openTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="close_time", type="time", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $closeTime;

}

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { 
  $weekday = $form["weekday"]->getData();
  $start_date = $form["todayDate"]->getData();
  $start_date = (string) $start_date->format('Y-m-d');
  $start_day = date('z', strtotime($start_date));
  $days_in_a_year = date('z', strtotime('2016-12-31'));  
  $number_of_days = ($days_in_a_year - $start_day) +1 ;
  for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_days; $i++) {
      $date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start_date)) . " +$i day");
      print date('d F - l', $date) .'<br />';
      if (in_array(date('l', $date), $weekday))
      {
        print "Match found".'<br />';
        $date_temp2 = date('Y-m-d',$date);
        print $date_temp2.'<br />';
        $date_temp = new \DateTime($date_temp2);
        $TodayDate = $date_temp->format('Y-m-d');
        $calendar2 = new Calendar();
        $calendar2->setTodayDate($TodayDate);
        $calendar2->setOpenTime($form["openTime"]->getData());
        $calendar2->setCloseTime($form["closeTime"]->getData());
        $calendar2->setIsBusinessDay(true);
        $calendar2->setIsHoliday(false);
        $em->persist($calendar2);
      }
      else
      {
        print "Match not found".'<br />';
        $calendar2 = new Calendar();
        $calendar2->setIsBusinessDay(false);
        $calendar2->setIsHoliday(true);
        $em->persist($calendar2);
       }
      }
    $em->flush(); 
   }
```

Actually I want to get Year only from user. Get First day of Year and store in database adding one increment day.
In If Block it prints the date of whole Year. to

```
30 December - Friday
Match found
2016-12-30
31 December - Saturday
Match not found
```

And At th end I am getting this error

> Error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Comment: instead of these  line:- `$date_temp = new \DateTime($date_temp2);$TodayDate = $date_temp->format('Y-m-d');` write one line:-`$TodayDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date_temp2));`

Comment: which line you got this error?  can you mark that on code?

Comment: @SarangaR That is why I am unable to debug, because it prints the all dates that i print in the block. But at the end the error arise.

Comment: make sure member function format() call from object. use var_dump and check that is object or not try this

Comment: @SarangaR By var_dump it dump all dates to `string '2016-12-30' (length=10)` except the last `2016-12-31`. I think the error is here?

Comment: @MTaqi I thought so because these type of error always have simple issue like this. Is your problem solved?

Comment: @SarangaR I update the code to ` $date_temp2 = date('Y-m-d',$date); $TodayDate = new \DateTime($date_temp2);` and it works Now.

Comment: @MTaqi okay, So if my answer helpful for you please up vote my comments

Answer (score 0):

The `$start_date` coming from `$form['todayDate']` is surely `null`.

Add a check to prevent this error.

Change :

```
$start_date = $form['todayDate'];
```

To :

```
$start_date = $form['todayDate'] ?: new \DateTime();
```

Like this, you get the current date as `DateTime` object and can use `format('Y-m-d')` .